# Is it possible to dupe my current Pop! OS (20.04)system, data, everything from SSD hardrive to persistent USB?

Tags: usb, persistence

I saw Matt Zabojnik’s article on the Medium website. (How to make a Pop!_OS Persistent Live USB).
My question is, I want to dupe my current setup (settings, files, programs etc) from my current SSD with pop! os 20.04. (I am hoping I don’t have to start fresh but will do it if need be.
So I want to make a current copy of my already running Pop! OS and make it run on a USB stick with persistence. 
Is that possible? Or do I need to put a fresh copy of Pop! OS on the usb stick and then rebuild all my files, settings from scratch. Any assistance is appreciated. 
Thanks!
Rand

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, most of your personal configuration is in your home directory, so backing up and copying that would be 90%. For files, you can have `apt` list the programs installed and then re-install them on the other build.

Comment: Thanks Aaron! I’ll give it a go. 
randy